# How to speed up the swipe & scrolling in mobile using Javascript, CSS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have trouble about lazy scrolling in iPhone devices.
The app was built in Vue.js.

I improved the scrolling speed in desktop using Javascript but it doesn't work in mobile devices due to swipe.

Is there anyone who knows how to speed up the swipe & scrolling in mobile devices?

Comment: [`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling)

Comment: For the native feeling scrolling, see @LarsBeck's answer.

if you want to detect swipe gestures, take a look at hammer.js ; https://hammerjs.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use with overflow property:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-moz-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: There's no `-moz-overflow-scrolling`